# Using the power reduction formula to rewrite the equation in terms of cosine

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\cos^2x\sin^4x$$

Steps I took:

I already know that $\sin^{ 4 }x=\left(\frac { 3-4\cos2x+\cos4x }{ 8 } \right)$

So now I must do:

$$\frac { 1+\cos2x }{ 2 } \cdot\frac { 3-4\cos2x+\cos4x }{ 8 } =
\frac { 3-4\cos2x+\cos4x+3\cos2x-4\cos^{ 2 }2x+\cos2x\cos4x }{ 16 }=\frac { 3-\cos2x+\cos4x+\cos2x\cos4x-4\left(\tfrac { 1+\cos4x }{ 2 } \right) }{ 16 }$$

This is where I came to a screeching halt. I know that I must now get rid of the fraction in the numerator and continue combining like terms and simplifying the expression. However, if I multiply the numerator and denominator by $2$, It gives me a different denominator than the correct answer should have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$=\frac { 1+\cos2x }{ 2 } \cdot\frac { 3-4\cos2x+\cos4x }{ 8 } =
\frac { 3-4\cos2x+\cos4x+3\cos2x-4\cos^{ 2 }2x+\cos2x\cos4x }{ 16 }=\frac { 3-\cos2x+\cos4x+\cos2x\cos4x-4\left(\tfrac { 1+\cos4x }{ 2 } \right) }{ 16 }$$

$$=\frac{3-cos2x+cos4x+cos2xcos4x-2-2cos4x}{16}$$
$$=\frac{1-cos2x-cos4x+cos2xcos4x}{16}$$

Comment: I just realized what you said a few moments after I replied to your comment. I just wrote it out and came to the same answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{align}
\cos^2x\sin^4x &=\frac{1+\cos2x}{2} \cdot\frac{3-4\cos2x+\cos4x}{8}\\
&=\frac{3-4\cos2x+\cos4x+3\cos2x-4\cos^{2}2x+\cos2x\cos4x}{16}\\
&=\frac{3-\cos2x+\cos4x+\cos2x\cos4x-4\left(\frac{1+\cos4x}{2} \right)}{16}\\
&=\frac{3-\cos2x+\cos4x+\cos2x\cos4x-2-2\cos4x}{16}\\
&=\frac{1-\cos2x-\cos4x+\cos2x\cos4x}{16}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

i have got after some simplifications
$$\frac{1}{32} (-\cos (2 x)-2 \cos (4 x)+\cos (6 x)+2)$$

Comment: That's what wolfram alpha gives me as well. The answer in the book is $\frac { 1 }{ 16 } (1-cos2x-cos4x+cos2xcox4x)$

Comment: That what you get when you cancel out the 4 by 2 then distribute -2 to $1+cos4x$

Comment: @Earth52 would you please be able to show me that? I can't quite see what you mean

Comment: -4(1+cos4x/2) = -2-2cos4x

Comment: @Earth52 To be honest, I am not quite seeing how to go from the last step I arrived at to any of these answers.